# Subset of rows containing '.' as missing values instead of NA in a chosen column of a data frame

Tags: r

We have a data frame from a tab delimited file. The data frame NCNT has columns 2 and 3 with observed values as A,G,T,C and missing data represented as '.' instead of NA.

We would like to use the subset command to define a new data frame newNCNT such that it only contains rows that have the missing value '.' value from columns 2 and 3.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question does not contain a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/4303162). It is therefore hard to understand your problem and give you an appropriate answer. Please make your data available (e.g. by using `dput()`) or use one of the example data sets in R. Also, add the minimal code required to reproduce your problem to your post.

Comment: Without a reproducible example, all we can do is guess - for example it might be `subset(NCNT, rowSums(NCNT[2:3] == ".") > 0)`

Comment: Thank you so much @docendo discimus. The code worked.

Comment: @Stibu, sorry, I will post the minimal code and reproducible example the next time.

Answer (score 1):

This should deliver the desired subset using ordinary logical indexing and logical operators:

```
newNCNT <- NCNT[ NCNT[[2]] == "." & NCNT[[3]] == ".", ]
```

In order to use the `subset` function one would ordinarily need to know the column names for those two columns. If one knew the names to be `name1` and `name2` then it might be:

```
newNCNT <- subset( NCNT, name1 == "." & name2 == ".")
```

This will deliver rows where *both* values in those columns are ".". Many people have difficulty expressing their desired logical operations correctly, so if you wanted  rows with *either* column 2 or column 3 having a missing value then you would need the `|` (OR) operator. @docendodiscimus apparently thought you wanted the latter.

Comment: Thank you @42- for your help.